# How can I have a calendar with date as horizontal rows and time in vertical columns

Tags: android, android-layout, calendar, android-custom-view, android-calendar

the title says it all. I've looked into android arsenal but couldn't find anything that fit my needs. I need to have all the functionality of calendar. Person1 and Person2 can be any string. the only problem is the horizontal dates with vertical columns time. How do I do that? any links can get me started would be fine. Thanks.

[image: this calendar]

Comment: This arrangement can be done with 2 `RecyclerView`  one for Date one for Time .. Whats So tricky ?

Comment: I thought it was tricky. But it's damn easy.. apologies.

Answer (score 0):

multiple recyclerView will help you to achieve this ... date-picker in one and time-picker in another align them in horizontal and vertical as needed.