# integrate two recyclerview like viewpager and tablayout(animating)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

Well, It's a follow up question which I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58908516/how-can-i-have-a-calendar-with-date-as-horizontal-rows-and-time-in-vertical-colu/58909031#58909031).

Now I have a two `RecyclerViews` one for the date and the other for the time. I need to use some way to connect them both so they can have a `ViewPager` and `TableLayout` integration animation. swiping will just make me select the next date and the time. So, I have my layout file as follow. any alternative to `ViewPager` will be fine. I need to have some sort of animation when the date changes. So UX does not get all crazy.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    ArrayList<String> setUpDatesList;

    RecyclerView dateRV;
    ChipDatesAdapter chipAdapter;

    RecyclerView timeRV;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setUpDatesList = new ArrayList<>();
        dateRV = findViewById(R.id.chip_group_rv);
        timeRV = findViewById(R.id.time_rv);


        setUpDates();
        setUpTimes();
    }

    ChipTimeAdapter chipTimeAdapter;
    ArrayList<String> timeArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    void setUpTimes() {



        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        int startDate = cal.get(Calendar.DATE);
        while (cal.get(Calendar.DATE) == startDate) {

            String timeIs = df.format(cal.getTime());
            System.out.println(timeIs);
            cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
            timeArrayList.add(timeIs);
        }
        chipTimeAdapter = new ChipTimeAdapter(timeArrayList);


        timeRV.setAdapter(chipTimeAdapter);
        timeRV.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,4));

    }

    void setUpDates() {
        chipAdapter = new ChipDatesAdapter();
        Calendar getAll30DaysCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        for (int i = 0; i < 31; i++) {
            SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
            String formattedDate = df.format(getAll30DaysCalendar.getTime());
            setUpDatesList.add(formattedDate);
            System.out.println(formattedDate.substring(0, 6));
            getAll30DaysCalendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }
        chipAdapter.setUpDates(setUpDatesList);
        dateRV.setAdapter(chipAdapter);
        dateRV.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
    }
}
```

**DatesAdapter.java**

```
public class ChipDatesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ChipDatesAdapter.chipViewHolder> {

    ArrayList<String> datesString;
    int lastSelectedPosition = 0;

    void setUpDates(ArrayList<String> chipArrayList) {
        datesString = new ArrayList<>();
        datesString = chipArrayList;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public chipViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_chip_dates, parent, false);

        return new chipViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final chipViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        holder.chip.setText(datesString.get(position));

        holder.chip.setChecked(lastSelectedPosition == position);

    }

    public static final String TAG = ChipDatesAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return datesString.size();
    }

    class chipViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        Chip chip;


        public chipViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            chip = itemView.findViewById(R.id.chip_item);

            chip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    lastSelectedPosition = getAdapterPosition();
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });

        }
    }

}
```

**TimeAdapter.java**

```
public class ChipTimeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ChipTimeAdapter.ChipTimeViewHolder> {

    int lastPosition = -1;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ChipTimeViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_chip_time, parent, false);


        return new ChipTimeViewHolder(view);
    }

    ChipTimeAdapter(ArrayList<String> correctTime) {
        this.correctTimeList = correctTime;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ChipTimeViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        holder.time.setText(correctTimeList.get(position));

        holder.time.setChecked(lastPosition == position);



    }

    ArrayList<String> correctTimeList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return correctTimeList.size();
    }

    class ChipTimeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        RadioButton time;

        public ChipTimeViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            time = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_time);

            time.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    lastPosition = getAdapterPosition();
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });

        }

    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">



        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/chip_group_rv"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/time_rv"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**item_chips_date.xml**

```
 <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/chip_item"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"


    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Choice"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearance"

    app:chipBackgroundColor="@color/bg_chip_color_selector_state"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:focusable="true">

</com.google.android.material.chip.Chip>
```

**item_chips_time.xml**

```
<RadioButton android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:button="@android:color/transparent"
    android:id="@+id/item_time"

    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:textColor="@color/selector_time"
    android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_medium_0"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

</RadioButton>
```